# Getting the prompt from the remote terminal over ssh

Tags: c, ssh

I have a simple program test which gets a number as input and prints the same on console.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   int i;
   printf("Test Pgm \n");
   printf("Enter a no:");
   scanf("%d",&i);
   printf("No Inputted:%d \n",i);
   return 0;
}
```

//The above program lies on 10.220.5.xx (different machine)

```
##gcc -o test test.c
```

On invoking the test pgm frm another machine over ssh , I don't get any prompt on the machine where im executing.

```
$ ssh user@10.220.3.xx '/home/user/test'
user@10.220.3.xx's password
```

After entering the password i don't get see anything not even 'Test Pgm'. How do i get the prompt remotely and input the values?

Comment: Try a `fflush(stdout)` right after the first `printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `fflush(stdout);` before the `scanf()`.

Also, you must check the return value of `scanf()`, it can fail to convert the input if given non-numerical text:

```
fflush(stdout);
if(scanf("%d", &i) == 1)
  printf("Number input: %d\n", i);
```